# Add component with Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout

Is possible add a component in layout android through a Floating Action Button?
Because, using the regular button work very well.

Regular button (worked well):

```
btn.setOnclickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment frag = new Fragment();
        frag.addSpinner;
    }
});
```

FAB

```
fab.setOnclickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment frag = new Fragment();
        frag.addSpinner;
    }
});
```

Fragment class

```
public void addSpinner () {
    Spinner spnAdd = new Spinner(getActivity());
    layoutDinamic.addView(spnAdd);
}
```

LOG:

```
              --------- beginning of crash
              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.victorvicari.actionbarteste, PID: 2714
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:364)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3788)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3892)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:246)
                  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:70)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:232)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:199)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:154)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:139)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:112)
                  at com.example.victorvicari.actionbarteste.Fragments.Fase2Fragment.addSpinner(Fase2Fragment.java:81)
                  at com.example.victorvicari.actionbarteste.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: what's your exact question?

Comment: if it works with a basic button, then it should definitely works with a fab, can you explicit more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. FloatingActionButton is an ImageButton. You can use to perform for any action.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);//pass activity or context

Comment: I did, and bug remains